# Not able to capture image Opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

Not able to capture Image, works in other laptop, my webcam is not able to open.But it works in other laptop.The output is "Error:Capture is Null"

```
#include "cv.h" 
 #include "highgui.h" 
 #include <stdio.h>  
 // A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
 int main() {
   CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
   if ( !capture ) {
     fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
     getchar();
     return -1;
   }
   // Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
   cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
   while ( 1 ) {
     // Get one frame
     IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
     if ( !frame ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
       getchar();
       break;
     }
     cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
     // Do not release the frame!
     //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
     //remove higher bits using AND operator
     if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
   }
   // Release the capture device housekeeping
   cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
   cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try different numbers in the place of CV_CAP_ANY.

It is also possible that your OpenCV is not installed appropriately, then you should reinstall it with libv4l as it is suggested [here](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/CvCapture-capture-cvCaptureFromCAM-CV-CAP-ANY-Return-NULL-UBUNTU-td6951521.html).

There is a slight chance that your camera is not [compatible](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS) with OpenCV.

Comment: 1. i tried my usb webcam it still didnt work 2. I m using visual studio.23. I will try reinstall it using my .exe setup and getback to u sonn... thanks@rics

Comment: If you are working with Windows then this page (http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/Windows7AndOpenCV) can be helpful to you. It suggests VideoInputFrameGrabber instead of capture. (I have not tried it so far.)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `-1` instead of `CV_CAP_ANY`.